# Play! Authenticate verification email

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, play-authenticate

I have been working through the play authentication usage getting started guide:

https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/blob/master/samples/java/Getting%20Started.md

I have got to the stage where users can login with a gmail or openID account or they can create a new account. Is there a way I can modify the text of the verification email that is sent to users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, modifying templates and emails is one of the key points of the PA, check templates in:

https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/tree/master/samples/java/play-authenticate-usage/app/views/account/email

**hint:** Turn on `smtp.mock` in your config, so you won't need to spam your mail for tests, just in `application.conf`, place somewhere at the end the line (don't forget to remove it for the production):

```
smtp.mock=true
```